# How to fetch this data with Beautiful Soup 4 or lxml?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

Here's the website in question:

https://www.gurufocus.com/stock/AAPL

And the part that interests me is this one (it's the GF Score in the upper part of the website):

[image]

I need to extract the strings 'GF Score' and '98/100'.

Firefox Inspector gives me span.t-h6 > span:nth-child(1) as a CSS Selector but I just can't seem to fetch neither the numbers nor the descriptor.

Here's the code that I've used so far to extract the "GF Score" part:

```
import requests
import bs4 as BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html

req = requests.get('https://www.gurufocus.com/stock/AAPL')

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
score_soup = soup.select('#gf-score-section-003550 > span > span:nth-child(1)')
score_soup_2 = soup.select('span.t-h6 > span')
print(score_soup)
print(score_soup_2)

tree = html.fromstring(req.content)
score_lxml = tree.xpath ('//*[@id="gf-score-section-003550"]/span/span[1]')
print(score_lxml)
```

As a result, I'm getting three empty brackets.

The xpath was taken directly out of chrome via the copy function and the nth-child expression in the BS4 part also.

Any suggestions as to what might be at fault here?

Comment: Highly dynamic web page. Use selenium

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately get the page using Requests lib impossible, as well as access to the api to which the signature is needed.
There is 2 option:

Use [API](https://www.gurufocus.com/api/overview). It's not free, but much more convenient and faster.
And second one - [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). It's free, but the speed is without fine-tuning the wait element. The second problem is protection - cloudflare. Soon without changing the headers and\or IP you **probably** ll get a ban. So there is example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_gf_score(ticker_symbol: str, timeout=10):
    driver.get(f'https://www.gurufocus.com/stock/{ticker_symbol}/summary')
    try:
        element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, f'register-dialog-email-input'))
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
        return BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml').find('span', text='GF Score:').findNext('span').get_text(strip=True)
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Timed out waiting for page to load")


tickers = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'AMZN']
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
for ticker in tickers:
    print(ticker, get_gf_score(ticker), sep=': ')
```

OUTPUT:

```
AAPL: 98/100
MSFT: 97/100
AMZN: 88/100
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you could get the desired value is:

- Make the request to the page - by *pretending* the request comes from a browser and then, extract the info you need from the JSON object inside the `script` HTML tag<sup>1</sup>.

***NOTE:***

> <sup>1</sup> Please be warned there that I couldn't get the JSON
> object  -***This is the [JSON result](https://anotepad.com/notes/pgf8fbjn), btw***- and extract the value by following the path:
>
> ```
> js_data['fetch']['data-v-4446338b:0']['stock']['gf_score']
> ```

So, as alternative (*not a very good one, IMHO, but, works for your purpose, though*), I decided to find certain elements on the JSON/string result and then extract the desired value (*by dividing the string - i.e. substring*).

Full code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

geturl = r'https://www.gurufocus.com/stock/AAPL'

getheaders = {
    'Accept': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36',
    'Referer': 'https://www.gurufocus.com'
}

s = requests.Session()
r = requests.get(geturl, headers=getheaders)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

# This is the "<script>" element tag that contains the full JSON object 
# with all the data.
scripts = soup.findAll("script")[1]

# Get only the JSON data: 
js_data = scripts.get_text("", strip=True)

# -- Get the value from the "gf_score" string - by getting its position:

# Part I: is where the "gf_score" begins. 
part_I = js_data.find("gf_score")

# Part II: is where the final position is declared - in this case AFTER the "gf_score" value.
part_II = js_data.find(",gf_score_med")

# Build the desired result and print it: 
gf_score = js_data[part_I:part_II].replace("gf_score:", "GF Score: ") + "/100"
print(gf_score)
```

Result:

```
GF Score: 98/100
```

Answer (score -1):

the data is dynamic. I think `rank` is what you are looking for but the api required authentication. Maybe you can use `selenium` or `playwright` to render the page?

[image]